# Why is water evaporation not more commonly used to cool buildings

Tags: physical-chemistry, heat, phase

Water has a very high heat of vaporization (2260 kJ per kg). Why not just gradually sprinkle water on your roof to keep the building cool in opposed to using air conditioners?

It wouldn't take much water to keep the building a few degrees cooler for a long time. Air conditioners use a lot of electricity which is bad for the environment. I read some places ban water vaporization cooling systems because of droughts and because tap water is government subsidized but that seems silly.

As a society it would be cheaper and more environmentally friendly to use water. The water will simply evaporate and return as rain which it will do anyway regardless. The energy air conditioning uses puts more greenhouse gases  in the environment which (allegedly) causes more global warming and puts more chemicals in rain water.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Chemistry stack exchange. Would it be possible for you to do the following:
1) Break up your question into paragraphs if it is long to improve readability
2) Make sure that you are asking a discrete question and that that question is marked out clearly
3) In regards to AC electricity use vs water use, do you have any figures to support your claim other than "a lot of electricity" and "not much water"?

In addition, do you know for sure that water-cooling is not a system that people use? Are there situations where it is more or less amenable to use? (hints here)

Comment: No worries, I've made some edits. btw, here is some info that you might find useful http://www.yourhome.gov.au/technical/fs46.html#evaporative

Comment: Sprinkling water on roof is not as efficient as using a [evaporative cooler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaporative_cooler). Such coolers are widely used around the world. But as to why it is not as commonly used (I think in USA) is because of how a/c systems got marketed and also because most people prefer a relatively compact a/s system as opposed to a wet air cooler. Also wet air coolers do not work efficiently in high humidity places.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about common practice. This is not asking a chemistry question.

Comment: Hi @user2232, it looks like you accidentally created three different accounts while posting the question and your two comments below. Please [fill out this form](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to ask for them to be merge back together.

Comment: I'm going to put this one on hold, as it is physics rather than chemistry, and not really a question in its current form (more of an argumentative rant)…

Answer (score 1):

"This question seems rhetorically posed: how can you justify calling your solution better and cheaper without having run the numbers? – Aesin 1 hour ago"

A central air conditioning system for a house takes about 3500 watts.

http://michaelbluejay.com/electricity/howmuch.html

1 watt = 1 J/sec so that's about 1,260,0000 J/hour

A gallon of water weighs about 3.7854118 Kg

so at 2260 kJ per kg you can extract 6,780,000 J of energy per gallon of water which is more energy than the air conditioning system even uses and the air conditioning system doesn't extract the amount of heat energy from a building than the energy it uses.

If you run the numbers even with a gallon of water the energy efficiency of water usage is much superior than that of an air conditioning system.

The high heat of vaporization of water is how sweat keeps you cool. Ancient civilizations used to pour water on their tents or tepees or whatever to keep themselves cool. It's cheap and efficient. The superiority of this method when opposed to air conditioning, in dry areas at least, is very obvious. I have yet to see one good reason why it's not used more often.

Comment: Evaporative cooling systems exist and are used widely in Australia. See my link above. Part of the reason it's not used more, however, is 1) humid climates where it won't work as well 2) places where the scarcity of water outweighs the environmental concern from energy use

Answer (score 0):

Thank you buckminst. Your link was useful.

I do think much of the reason this method isn't used more often in the U.S. (in dry areas of course) has to do with marketing or perhaps bad laws passed for some convoluted political reasons. If more people used this in opposed to regular air conditioners it would easily substantially lower energy costs.

I also wanted to add some more numbers to bring perspective to how inefficient regular air conditioners are compared with evaporative cooling.

According to Wikipedia "a 5000 BTU/h air-conditioning unit, with a SEER of 10, would consume 5000/10 = 500 Watts of power on average."

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_conditioning#Seasonal_energy_efficiency_ratio

500 W = 1,800,000 J per hour

5000 BTU = 527,500 J of energy removed from the environment

Divide the two and you get about 30 percent efficiency, which is about the efficiency of a good regular air conditioner (so their example is realistic). A single gallon of water removes 6,780,000 J of heat energy from its environment.

So the central air conditioner uses about 12,600,000 J/hour (sorry I placed my commas wrong in the last post which confused me and drew me to an incorrect conclusion) and (assuming about 30 percent efficiency) will remove only about 3,780,000 J of energy from its environment. A single gallon of water will remove 6,780,000 J of energy from its environment which is enough to almost last two hours in opposed to using the central air conditioner for two hours.

Yet even in dry areas I do not see this used. I see regular air conditioners used and I think that needs to change.